# SQL Server - Finding Parent Source from T-SQL Snippet

Tags: sql-server, query, hashing

The environments for which I'm responsible have some pretty substantial plan non-reuse challenges.  I've run across the following query (h/t Brent Ozar blog commenter Michael J Swart) that does a fine job of itemizing the worst offenders:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT COUNT(*) [count], query_hash, min(sql_handle) [sql_handle_example]
   FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats
   GROUP BY query_hash
   )
SELECT cte.*, t.text [query_text_example]
FROM cte
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle_example) t
WHERE [count] > 100
ORDER BY [count] DESC
```

My challenge is taking a snip of the [query_text_example] text and efficiently identifying whether it's originating from a sproc, and if so which one in which database.  I've done some Googling and testing and it's been puzzlingly difficult to find a solution that takes a snippet of query text, whether it was dynamically built or not, and accurately identifies its parent sproc.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### parental advisory

You can use the [dm_exec_procedure_stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-procedure-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) view, and if you're on SQL Server 2016 or better, the [dm_exec_function_stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-function-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) view as well, to track down scalar UDFs.

Both of those views have an `object_id` column that can be used to resolve procedure and function names with the [OBJECT_NAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/object-name-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function. You can match those to various other views on the `sql_handle` or `plan_handle` column.

Unless you are doing this scoped to a single database that you care about, you may also need to use the [dm_exec_plan_attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-plan-attributes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) view to grab the `dbid` attribute, which can be used as a second argument in `OBJECT_NAME`.

Answer (score 2):

`dm_exec_sql_text` supplies a `objectid` column which is `NULL` for ad-hoc batches. You can just left-join it with `sys.objects`

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
      COUNT(*) [count],
      s.query_hash,
      min(s.sql_handle) [sql_handle_example]
    FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats s
    GROUP BY s.query_hash
    HAVING count(*) > 100
)
SELECT
  cte.*,
  t.text [query_text_example],
  o.name
FROM cte
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(cte.sql_handle_example) t
LEFT JOIN sys.objects o ON o.object_id = t.objectid
ORDER BY [count] DESC;
```

This only works for a single database. To join it across multiple unknown databases you need dynamic SQL. Each database has a separate `sys.objects`.